# AS3: finding an object by it Instance name in a dynamic added child

Tags: actionscript-3, air, instance, addchild

I am doing an Adobe AIR Kiosk app but I am having a little problem.

First step is to generate a webcam container:

```
var bandwidth:int = 0; 
var quality:int = 100;
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
camera.setQuality(bandwidth, quality);
camera.setMode(885,575,30,true);
var video:Video = new Video(885,575);
video.attachCamera(camera);
video.name = "camara";
webcam.addChild(video);
```

It works ok, the problem is that I want to apply to it a custom filter

It works ok if I write it this way:

```
MovieClip(parent).contenedor_postal.postal.webcam.filters = [filter];
```

But I want to affect only the child inside the clip "webcam" without affecting other MC's, so I write it like this:

```
MovieClip(parent).contenedor_postal.postal.webcam.camara.filters = [filter];
```

and does not work. I used to program in AS2, so maybe the trick is very simple but I can't find anything that works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the video has a name property "camara" then this should work:

```
MovieClip(parent).contenedor_postal.postal.webcam.getChildByName("camara").filters = [filter];
```